# Touch not working in kodi with waveshare 10.1 inch capacitive touch screen lcd

Tags: raspbian, kodi, openelec

I bought this lcd screen http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/10.1inch_HDMI_LCD_(H)_(with_case) for my raspberry pi 3.

This screen has a usb capacitive touch input.

I installed kodi 15 under raspbian os using following command:

```
 sudo apt-get install kodi
```

Touch works with raspbian os. However it does not work under kodi installed under raspbian os. It does not work with OpenElec as well.

I tried it with Kodi installed in Windows 10. The touch functionality works in Kodi in this case.

On issuing following command:

```
 lsusb
```

I get Microelectronics Joystick in FS Mode.

How do I make it work in Kodi installed in raspbian os?

Update:
I see mouse cursor on the middle of the screen when I touch to upper left part of the screen. My resolution is off as well.

I have added below to my config.txt but with no success for getting the resolution correct:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with this screen - after a few days of frustration, i found a fix for the touchscreen - see below.

I wanted just OSMC rather than Raspbian, but this should still work. The author has another tutorial for Xbian.

I had no luck with the config.txt either - but i was able to go into the Kodi settings and change the video output calibration - which worked well enough for me.

The touchscreen was only working in the top left corner too - after some research i found this;

Follow the steps here: http://markamc.traki-iski.co.uk/raspberry-pi-2-osmc-egalax-touchscreen

> By using a modified version of ts_calibrate for touchscreen calibration and python utility uinput-mapper, it’s possible to generate a user-input device even which handles the calibration transformations and gives additional BTN_LEFT/RIGHT functionality within KODI on the Raspberry Pi.

It's a rather long process - but i ended up with a perfect 10.1 inch touchscreen for my car media center :)

Comment: i had tried this tutorial before as well which did not work but I see there is an update to this tutorial. Will give it a shot. thanks